Is there a way to wait for a OctopusDeployReleaseTenanted@6 task?
I am configuring a pipeline in Azure DevOps to deploy an application via Octopus on a tenanted server. When using v5 of the task before, I had a way to wait for its completion by ticking the "Show deployment progress" checkbox.
New in v6 of the task is that there is a separate task for a tenanted deployment (OctopusDeployReleaseTenanted@6) which does not wait for completion anymore. So apparently Octopus introduced an await task like documented here. But it seems like it only supports the regular OctopusDeployRelease or OctopusRunBook task. Via the UI in Azure DevOps I cannot specify the name of my tenant-deployment step so I don't know how I can link the await task to my deployment task.
Anyone has an idea?
For some reason I don't have the Output Variables section:

And I am using the latest Octopus Deploy Integration extension (v6.0.750)



Via the UI in Azure DevOps I cannot specify the name of my tenant-deployment step

According to your description, it seems that you are using classic build/relase pipeline. To specify the name of one task in classic pipeline, you can do it via Reference name under Output Variables.
Add a reference name to your "Deploy Octopus Release to Tenants" task.

In the next "Await Octopus Task Completion" task, set Step to the reference name of your above task.


Thanks, but check my updated question. The strange thing is that I don't have the Output Variables section like in your screenshot.

What's the version of your "Octopus Deploy Integration" extension? It's 6.0.750 in my org. You can try to uninstall this extension and install it again.

I am using the latest (6.0.750) as well (see screenshot). I could still try uninstalling and reinstalling it... You never know...


Create a new pipeline and check if you can see Output Variables. 2. If it's convenient, you can install this extension in other organizations and check if you can see the Output Variables in the pipeline. So that we can know whether it's only related to one org or all orgs. 3. May I know the region of your affected org?


As Ziyang Liu's answer, we need to use Reference name under Output Variables to specify the name of my tenant-deployment step when using classic Pipeline.
From your screenshot, you are not able to see the Output Variables option in the task.
I can reproduce the same issue when adding the task to the Task Group.
For example:

The cause of the issue is that the Task Group doesn't support setting Output Variables for single task.
To solve this issue, you need to directly add the OctopusDeployReleaseTenanted@6 task to the Build or Release Pipeline job. Then you will see the Output Variables Option.
For example:

Or you can change to use YAML Pipeline for the deployment. In this case, you can directly define the name field.
For example:
steps:


- task: OctopusDeployReleaseTenanted@6
  name: taskname
  inputs:
    OctoConnectedServiceName: '124'
    ....

- task: OctopusAwaitTask@6
  inputs:
    Space: 'test'
    Step: 'taskname'

